Does GBoard respect forced dark theme?
If I force the dark theme in my app with AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES), should GBoard respect that and use the dark theme too?
It isn't for me and I'm wondering if that's by design.
I set it in onCreate() of both my application and activity. GBoard is configured to use both themes.

Keyboards are separate apps.  They have no idea what the theme of the app running when they're being used is.
